# How does julia know what path separator and root directory to use?

Tags: julia

Functions like `joinpath` use the appropriate OS-dependent separator when joining two paths (ie `/` on Linux, `\\` on Windows, etc). How do these functions know what separator to use?

Similarly, the root directory on Linux is `/`, but on Windows is probably `C:\\`. Is there a way to retrieve the OS-dependent root directory in Julia?

Note, I've had a look at the `joinpath` [source on github](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/path.jl), and it appears to use an undocumented function `pathsep(a,b)` and a global variable `path_separator_re`, but I can't see how either of these work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the `Sys.isunix` and `Sys.iswindows` functions in order to conditionally define the correct `path_separator_re` variables, etc.

- https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/5c3f58039525972b24930f356821af8299f70a26/base/path.jl#L19-L41

---

```rb
if Sys.isunix()
    # ...
    const path_separator_re = r"/+"
    # ...

    splitdrive(path::String) = ("",path)
elseif Sys.iswindows()
    # ...
    const path_separator_re = r"[/\\]+"
    # ...

    function splitdrive(path::String)
        m = match(r"^([^\\]+:|\\\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+|\\\\\?\\UNC\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+|\\\\\?\\[^\\]+:|)(.*)$", path)
        String(m.captures[1]), String(m.captures[2])
    end
else
    error("path primitives for this OS need to be defined")
end
```

---

For the root directory, check out the `homedir` function, which uses `libuv` to determine it.

- https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/5c3f58039525972b24930f356821af8299f70a26/base/path.jl#L52-L77

> help?> homedir
>   search: homedir
>
> `homedir() -> AbstractString`
>     Return the current user's home directory.
>
> | Note
>     |
>     |  homedir determines the home directory via `libuv`'s `uv_os_homedir`. For details (for example on how to specify the home
>     |  directory via environment variables), see the `uv_os_homedir`  documentation.

Comment: Very interesting answer. Thank you.